# How to extend prototype of an object and have the same function in global scope as well?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to setup shorthands for several DOM accessor methods, namely - `getElementsByClassName` (`qCls`), `getElementById` (`qId`), `querySelector` (`q`), `querySelectorAll` (`Q`) - such that they are available:

1. in the global scope: I should be able to write `q(selector)` as a shorthand for `document.querySelector(selector)` throughout my code (in any scope or context).
2. as a property on DOM elements: I should be able to write `paragraph.q(selector)` as a shorthand for `paragraph.querySelector(selector)`.

I know the manual way to do this is:

```js
window.Q = function(sel){
    console.dir(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
};

Node.prototype.Q = function(sel){
    console.dir(this.querySelectorAll(sel));
};


// TEST
var p = document.querySelector("p");

Q("a"); // should have two elements
p.Q("a"); // should have one element
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<p><a>2</a></p>
```

But this has **duplicacy** - repeating exactly the same function again with only a minor difference (`document` vs `this`) - so **I intend to eliminate that duplicacy**.<sup>1</sup>

Now, what I think would work to achieve this is a pattern like:

```
window.Q = helperFunc(someFlag);
Node.prototype.Q = helperFunc(someOtherFlag);
```

where the `helperFunc` handles the logic for the return value, based on the flags. Based on this, I wrote the following:

```
function outputQFunc(context) {
    return function(selector) {
        console.dir(context.querySelectorAll("a"));
    };
}

window.Q = outputQFunc(document);
Node.prototype.Q = outputQFunc(this);
```

However, this has the obvious downside that the `this` context for `Node.prototype.Q` permanently points to the global scope, instead of the node which called this function. I could instead eliminate the `context`:

```
function outputQFunc() {
    return function(selector) {
        console.dir(this.querySelectorAll("a"));
    };
}
```

but then the `this` does not point to the `document` in case of the `window.Q`.

So, my question is, how to achieve this?

---

Notes:

1. While this duplicacy may sound trivial (it's only a single line!), I have actually shortened the code for MVCE. My actual code has to apply some `filter`s and stuff to the result of `doc.qsAll` before `return`ing it. In such cases, the duplicacy magnifies.

---

Once my query got resolved, if anyone is interested in the final code I reached, [this is it](http://jsfiddle.net/og7nt62j/21/), which I personally find very DRY and extensible:

```
var DOM_HELPERS = {
  /**
   * short hand for document.querySelector
   * @param {string} selector selector to match element
   */
  q: function(selector) {
    return this.querySelector(selector);
  },
  /**
   * short hand for document.querySelectorAll
   * @param {string} selector selector to match elements
   */
  Q: function(selector) {
    return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
  },
  /**
   * short hand for document.getElementById
   * @param {string} id selector to match element
   */
  qId: function(id) {
    return this.getElementById(id);
  },
  /**
   * short hand for document.getElementsByClassName
   * @param {string} cls selector to match elements
   */
  qCls: function(cls) {
    return this.getElementsByClassName(cls);
  }
};

for (var i = 0, funcs = Object.keys(DOM_HELPERS), len = funcs.length, funcName, func; i < len; i++) {
  funcName = funcs[i];
  func = DOM_HELPERS[funcName];
  window[funcName] = func.bind(document);
  Node.prototype[funcName] = func;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bind` on your helper function to specify a custom `this` context for `window.Q` (and use the default `this` otherwise, which will point to the proper calling context when called on a node):

```js
function qSA(sel) {
  console.dir(this.querySelectorAll(sel));
}


window.Q = qSA.bind(document);
Node.prototype.Q = qSA;

// TEST
var p = document.querySelector("p");

Q("a"); // should have two elements
p.Q("a"); // should have one element
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<p><a>2</a></p>
```